# Create avro schema for python dict

Tags: python, tuples, avro

I want to create an avro-schema for following python-dictionary:

```
d = {
    'topic': 'example', 
    'content': (
        { 'description': {'name': 'alex', 'value': 12}, 'id': '234ba' }, 
        { 'description': {'name': 'john', 'value': 14}, 'id': '823cx' }
    )
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the default serialization and deserialization included in the avro library for python?

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.0/gettingstartedpython.html

Verify that is what you want

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me